# Comparision trigger in Zabbix

Tags: monitoring, performance-monitoring, zabbix

I got two items created for showing certain values. One of them is shoving value from today and the other one from week ago. How can I create trigger that compares them and alert when one of them is lower than the other one by 15% or higher by 10%? I'm running on Zabbix 5.2

Comment: you could even do this using one item and using the time shift. In the trigger you can compare the item as it was a week ago with how the last value is. See https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/current/manual/config/triggers/expression

Answer (score 0):

[image]

to compare 2 items you can use an expression:

```
{Template Module Linux CPU by Zabbix agent active:system.cpu.load[all,avg1].last()}>{Template Module Linux CPU by Zabbix agent active:system.cpu.load[all,avg15].last()}
```

for example